# What's the syntax for setting selection keys for org-mobile-agenda views?

Tags: emacs, mobile-phone, org-mode

```
   The agendas that should be pushed to MobileOrg. Hide   
   Allowed values:

   default  the weekly agenda and the global TODO list
   custom   all custom agendas defined by the user
   all      the custom agendas and the default ones
   list     a list of selection key(s) as string.
```

I would like to push *only* the weekly agenda to the agendas.org file. What's the simplest way to go about this? It looks like selection keys is the way to go, but I didn't find any documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what is meant by "selection keys" is the actual keystrokes performed in the `C-c a` agenda menu; putting `a` as the argument gets me the weekly agenda view pushed to MobileOrg.